# how to truncate image from a section which contains both images and texts in html format

Tags: html, django, froala

i have made a description field which contains both images and texts. i have done this using froala editor.

now i want to display a thumbnail view which contains some part if description, so m using "truncatewords" tag for it.

The problem that i am facing is that when an image is before the text content than django is showing full image, which does not look good.

i don't want to diaplay any image of the description field in thumbnail view, only the text.

how can i do it?? please help

this is my html code line for that:

```
<div>{{card.desc|truncatewords:8|safe}}</div>
```

Comment: because your description use html tags you should use `truncatewords_html` instead of `truncatewords`

Comment: it didnt' work like i wanted.. it is still displaying the images.. i want just the text under <p> tag to be displayed... nothing else..

Comment: You should make a [`custom filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to remove the images and then truncate the HTML:

```html
<div>{{re.sub("(<img.*?>)", "", card.desc, 0, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)|truncatechars_html:8|safe}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display just text(no html tags) use [striptags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags).

```
{{ card.desc|striptags|truncatewords:8 }}
```

In this way, all html tags including images will be removed before displaying the text.